# Visx Streamgraph Custom Typing

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts, visualization, visx

I'm using visx to build a streamgraph for my application, but am very new to visx/d3. I'm able to generate the graph using a simple 2-d number array like in [this](https://airbnb.io/visx/streamgraph) example, but run into issues when modifying the input structure. In the example below, the goal is to generate a streamgraph that runs vertically downward as `t` increases, where `t` is a time in milliseconds and `value` is a number `[0,1]`. You can see it becomes necessary to modify the input data type with the inclusion of `t`, which may cause the vertical distance between points to vary. I'm fairly sure there's something I'm missing with the accessors, as logging shows all paths are `NaN` by the time they are passed into the `<Stack>` child method. Hoping someone can point out how I should be structuring and accessing the data here. Thanks!

```js
// t represents time in milliseconds, value represents value at that time
type Datum = {t: number, value: number}[];

export type StreamGraphProps = {
  data: Datum[]
  width: number;
  height: number;
  animate?: boolean;
};

export default function Streamgraph({data, width, height, animate = true}: StreamGraphProps) {
  if (data.length === 0) return null

  // Should represent the different series
  const keys = _.range(data[0].length);

  // Maximum value of t
  const tMax = data.reduce((max, cur) => Math.max(max, ...cur.map(v => v.t)), 0)

  // Scales
  const xScale = scaleLinear<number>({
    domain: [0, 1],
    range: [0, width],
  });
  const yScale = scaleLinear<number>({
    domain: [tMax, 0],
    range: [height, 0]
  });
  const colorScale = scaleOrdinal<number, string>({
    domain: keys,
    range: ['#ffc409', '#f14702', '#262d97', 'white', '#036ecd', '#9ecadd'],
  });
  const patternScale = scaleOrdinal<number, string>({
    domain: keys,
    range: ['gor', 'gpo', 'gpb', 'gpr', 'gpur', 'gsp', 'gtb'],
  });

  // x getter
  const getX = (d: SeriesPoint<Datum>, i: number) => xScale(d.data[i].value)
  // y0/y1 getters
  const getY0 = (d: SeriesPoint<Datum>) => yScale(d.data[0].t)
  const getY1 = (d: SeriesPoint<Datum>) => yScale(d.data[1].t)

  if (width < 10) return null

  return (
    <svg width={width} height={height}>
      <GradientPinkBlue id={"gpb"}/>
      <GradientPurpleOrange id={"gpo"}/>
      <GradientOrangeRed id={"gor"}/>
      <GradientPinkRed id={"gpr"}/>
      <GradientPurpleRed id={"gpur"}/>
      <GradientSteelPurple id={"gsp"}/>
      <GradientTealBlue id={"gtb"}/>

      <Group>
        <Stack<Datum, number>
          data={data}
          keys={keys}
          offset="silhouette"
          order='insideout'
          color={colorScale}
          x={getX}
          y0={getY0}
          y1={getY1}
          curve={curveCatmullRom}
        >
          {({stacks, path}) => {
            return stacks.map((stack) => {
              const pathString = path(stack) || '';
              const tweened = animate ? useSpring({pathString}) : {pathString};
              const color = colorScale(stack.key);
              const pattern = patternScale(stack.key);
              return (
                <g key={`series-${stack.key}`}>
                  <animated.path d={tweened.pathString} fill={color}/>
                  <animated.path d={tweened.pathString} fill={`url(#${pattern})`}/>
                </g>
              );
            })
          }}
        </Stack>
      </Group>
    </svg>
  );
}
```